# Ensure consistence for foreignkeys/ownerships in microservices

Tags: rest, reference, foreign-keys, microservices

I have two bounded contexts which lead into two micro services

- PersonalManagement
- DocumentStorage

I keep the entity model simple here.

PersonalManagement:

```
Entity/Table Person:
@id - int
tenantId - int
name - string
...
```

DocumentStorage

```
Entity/Table Document:
@id - int
tenantId - int
personId - int
dateIssued - string
...
```

You need to know that before the application is started - a company (tenant) is choosen to define the company context.

I want to store a new document by using REST/JSON.

This is a POST to /tenants/1/persons/5/documents

```
with the body
{
    "dateIssued" : "2018-06-11"
}
```

On the backend side - I validate the input body.

One validation might be "if the person specified exists and really belongs to given tenant".

Since this info is stored in the PersonalManagement-MicroService, I need to provide an operation like this:

```
"Does exists (personId=5,tenantId=1)"
```

in PersonalManagement to ensure consistence since caller might be evil.

Or in general:

What is best practise to check "ownership" of entities cross database in micro services

It might also be an option that if a new person is created (tenantId,personId) this information is stored additionally(!) in DocumentStorage but wanna avoid this redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to extend this answer into whether your bounded contexts and service endpoints are well defined since your question seems to be simplifying the issue to keep a well defined scope, but regarding your specific question:

> What is best practise to check "ownership" of entities cross database in micro services

Microservice architectures use strive for a "share nothing" principle. And that usually extends from code base to data base. So you're right to assume you're checking for this constraint "cross-DB" in your scenario.

You have a few options on this particular case, each with their set of drawbacks:

1) Your proposed **"Does exists (personId=5,tenantId=1)"** call from the *DocumentContext* to the *PersonContext* is not wrong on itself, but you will generate a straight dependency between these two microservices, so you must ask yourself whether it seems ok for you not to accept new documents if the *PersonManagement* microservice is offline.

In specific situations, such dependencies might be acceptable but the more of these you have, the less your microservice architecture will behave as one and more like a "distributed monolith" which on itself it pretty much an anti-pattern.

2) The other main option you have is that you should recognize that the *DocumentContext* is a very much interested in some information/behavior relating to *People* so it should be ok with modelling the *Person Entity* inside its boundaries.

That means, you can have the *DocumentContext* subscribe for changes in the *PersonContext* to be aware of which *People* currently exist and what their characteristics are and thus being able to keep a local copy of such information.

That way, your validation will be kept entirely inside the *DocumentContext* which will have its operation unhindered by eventual issues with the *PersonContext* and you will find out your modelling of the document related entities will be much cleaner than before.

But in the end, you will also discover that a *"share nothing"* principle usually will cost you in what seems to be redundancy, but it's actually independence of contexts.

Answer (score 1):

just for the tenancy check , this can be done using the JWT token (token which can store tenancy information and other metadata).

Let me provide another example of the same scenario which can't be solved with JWT.

Assume one Customer wants to create a Order and our system wants to check whether the customer exist or not while creating the order.

As Order and Customer service are separate, and we want minimal dependencies between them, there are multiple sol. to above problems:

- create Order in "validating state" and on OrderCreated event check for customer validity and update customer state to "Valid"
- another one before creating order check for the customer (which is not the right way as it creates dependency, untill and unless very critical do not do it)
- last way is the let the order be created , somebody who will final check the order for delivery will verify customer will remove